# I started working as a Manual Tester in an IT firm. What practices should Iapply to be a good tester?

Tags: manual-testing, quality-assessment, application-software-testing

I need some guidance regarding how I can make sure of the quality of that product.

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/41720/40022 does this answer your question

Comment: Thankyou it did help me in a good way

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/41722/40022  hope my answer gives you more clarity on what to do . All the best

Answer (score 1):

Start with mindset of below:

1. Creative test approach.
2. How I can break the code.
3. Cover maximum functionality with Minimum scenarios.
4. Learn Product and Functionality. (Be a functional expert).
5. Document your product experience and Share with people around you.
6. Adopt Devops Agile (You can google about them.

Last but not lease.
7. Be Proactive in approach and neutral in communication

Comment: why would you limit the scenarios you test ?

Comment: What I mean is.. instead of adding 1 scenario for one Functional case try whether you can cover 2 to 3 function cases in single scenario so that Trace matrix clearity can be maintained.

Comment: Testing functionality without thinking of use case is a bad approach. You can have 10 scenarios that test the same feature. But what you meant is to avoid writing the same scenario 10 times to cover 10 features, then ya you are right. You can club all the 10 features inside the single use-case where possible

Comment: @PDHide I didn't mean that. 
For example :  Take an example of Ecommerce where you need to test below functionality: 
1. all the products which supports the  same day delivery.
2. Different payment method like Visa, Mastercard, paypal.

Now in this case instead of writing individual cases separately (ie one for products and one for payment methods) you can cover both these combination with one or more test cases.it not only make your scenarios more meaningful but also easy to make Tracebility Matrix to stakeholders

hope it is clear now...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, so you could tell that "make sure your scenarios are end to end". So you're actually testing a complete workflow than a single feature, and that should be the right approach thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Learn and practice.**

You can start learning from various books and blogs. Here are some post suggestions for those:

- [books](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/42/what-books-would-you-recommend-to-start-learning-about-software-testing)
- [blogs](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/336/blogs-to-follow-to-further-learning)

Parallel with that, start actually practicing your testing skills. See [these](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17700/qa-testing-training-and-practice) [posts](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7621/how-to-become-a-good-qa-employee).

After that, you might invest some time in [tools](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5624/typical-software-tools-short-list-for-manual-qa-specialist-tester-working) and [automation](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3798/good-resources-tutorials-tips-for-beginner-doing-automation), if that is what you are after.